# In Codeigniter unable to use order_by random

Tags: php, codeigniter

unable to use order_by random in codeigniter

My Code is:

```
function fetch_popular_news()
{
    $query=$this->db->order_by('id','rand')->limit(1)->get('main_slider');
    $data=$query->result();
    return $data;
}
```

i also tried:

```
function fetch_popular_news()
{
    $query=$this->db->order_by('id','RANDOM')->limit(1)->get('main_slider');
    $data=$query->result();
    return $data;
}
```

but it's not working...

Comment: use RANDOM instead of rand and see ..

Comment: i tried..but it's not showing any result...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this instead, it will work:

```
order_by('rand()')
```

Comment: it's showing result, but not changing by rand...it's showing only one record because of limit 1

Comment: yes, it should show...but it's only showing same result

Comment: refresh the page, or check the query its executing,

Answer (score 0):

In codeignitor you need to specify it as follows

```
function fetch_popular_news()
{
    $this->db->order_by('id', 'RANDOM');
    $this->db->limit(1);
    $query = $this->db->get('main_slider');
    return $query->result_array();

}
```

Another way would be

```
function fetch_popular_news()
{
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM main_slider ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1');
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Comment: Strange why no result is being returned. I've included another example in my answer.

Comment: note that thing..order by rand used individually..not with any another columns....

Comment: Ordering by Id then RAND will never return a random result as ID will be unique and always return id = 1 as this SQL is limited to 1

Answer (score 0):

Friends I have found the solution

```
$query=$this->db->order_by('rand()')->limit(1)->get('main_slider');
```

anyway thanks to every one for help me...